# Process mount is read only

Tags: filesystems, systemd, redis

I have a rw file system `/myraid0`.

```
# cat /proc/mounts | grep myraid0
/dev/mapper/isw_cfdbejjgdi_myraid0p1 /myraid0 ext4 rw,relatime,stripe=8,data=ordered 0 0
```

I have no problem writing to `/myraid0` as any user.

```
redis@host:~$ echo hi > /myraid0/tmp/redis/test
redis@host:~$ cat /myraid0/tmp/redis/test
hi
```

However, my process can't write a file on `/myraid0`, due to `EROFS` (Read-only file system).

```
open("temp-4036.rdb", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = -1 EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

This shows the process views the mount as ro.

```
# cat /proc/15920/mounts | grep myraid0
/dev/mapper/isw_cfdbejjgdi_myraid0p1 /myraid0 ext4 ro,relatime,stripe=8,data=ordered 0 0
```

Why does the process only have read only view of the mount?

Thanks!

## Additional details

- Ubuntu 16.04
- `Linux jeff-apartment-2015 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- App is `redis-server`. It's failing to save the snapshots to a non-root device
- Redis error is

> Failed opening .rdb for saving: Read-only file system

- Installed version 3.0.6 via `apt-get`
- Launched by `systemd`
- Listing of `/proc/15920/ns` (requested by @VenkatC):
  `lrwxrwxrwx 1 redis redis 0 Sep 16 05:39 cgroup -> cgroup:[4026531835]
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 redis redis 0 Sep 15 18:03 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 redis redis 0 Sep 15 18:03 mnt -> mnt:[4026532343]
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 redis redis 0 Sep 15 18:03 net -> net:[4026531957]
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 redis redis 0 Sep 15 18:03 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 redis redis 0 Sep 15 18:03 user -> user:[4026531837]
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 redis redis 0 Sep 15 18:03 uts -> uts:[4026531838]`
- `apparmor_status  | grep redis` returns nothing (requested by @Gilles)
- Nothing else in the logs more informative than the strace output.

## Process namespaces

Working bash shell for redis user

```
ls -l /proc/7359/ns/mnt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 redis redis 0 Sep 15 18:03 /proc/7359/ns/mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
```

Not working redis process

```
ls -l /proc/15920/ns/mnt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 redis redis 0 Sep 15 18:03 /proc/15920/ns/mnt -> mnt:[4026532343]
```

Working bash shell for my user

```
ls -atlrh /proc/7138/ns/mnt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jeff jeff 0 Sep 15 18:03 /proc/7138/ns/mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
```

Comment: Can you post listing of /proc/$$/ns (your shell) and /proc/15920/ns ? The process might be running in different mount namespace

Comment: Are you sure that the process is writing in the desired directory? Are there any security restrictions (e.g. SELinux, AppArmor, …)? Does anything appear in the system logs when the process fails to access that file?

Comment: Updated question for @Gilles.

Comment: Please post the full error redis generates (relevant source code is at https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3793afa0ba4a214c1e25ed74309d0594e7a1490c/src/rdb.c, line 958, suggests you should see error along lines of "Failed opening the RDB file %s (in server root dir %s) for saving: %s".

Comment: Updated question for @VenkatC. It looks like it's in its own process namespace!

Comment: Updated question for @steve. That's not the exact line I'm getting. apt installed 3.0.6, but 3.2.3 is released. I didn't find any closed tickets, but I could have missed it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see, redis process is running in it's own 'mount namespace', with readonly option.

```
Redis proc started by Systemd [/proc/15920/ns/mnt] -> mnt:[4026532343]

your shell [/proc/7138/ns/mnt] -> mnt:[4026531840]
```

Look at systemd unit for the `redis-server` startup and update options related to the mountflags to suit your needs

Looking at redis-server systemd unit file, I see below settings

```
# grep -i readwrite /etc/systemd/system/redis.service 
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/redis
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/log/redis
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/run/redis
ReadWriteDirectories=-/etc/redis
```

so you could add /myraid0 as an additional `ReadWriteDirectories` and restart redis service